# conda activate with ksh

Tags: conda, ksh

I have been struggling with how to activate a conda environment with ksh. The problem has already been pointed out here : https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7843

```
conda activate <path_to_env>

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

There are plenty of solutions for bash, zsh etc but I did not find a way to make it work with ksh (`conda init ksh` or `eval "$(conda shell.ksh hook)"` does not seem to work). Would have anyone any tips to overcome this issue ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try the specific suggestions in the github ticket 7843 that you reference in your question?  Stackoverflow does not seem to be the correct place to progress a ticket that is still open on github.  Maybe also think about the true reason you want ksh support here.